# Are there any obvious reasons $g_2^3-27g_3^2$ a cusp form?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Recall that $G_k(\tau)$ are Eisenstein series$(k\geq 2)$ defined over upper half plane $\mathcal{H}$. Now define $g_2=60G_4,g_3=140G_6$ and $\Delta=(g_2)^3-27(g_3)^2$. Note that $\Delta$ corresponds to elliptic curve's discriminant defined by Wierstrass form $\mathcal{P}'^2=\mathcal{P}^3-g_2\mathcal{P}-g_3$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Are there obvious reasons that $\Delta$ is a cusp form? I can compute fourier expansion constant term vanishing but this relies heavily upon $\zeta(2k)$'s concrete form in terms of Bernouille numbers.

Ref. Diamond, Schurman A First Course in Modular Forms(4th Ed), Ex 1.7(d).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a complex torus/elliptic curve reason.

- $z \mapsto (\wp_\tau(z),\wp_\tau'(z))$ is an [isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions#Invariants) $\mathbb{C}/(\mathbb{Z}+\tau \mathbb{Z}) \to E_\tau/\mathbb{C} : y^2 = 4x^3-g_2(\tau) x-g_3(\tau)$ (with $20 g_2(\tau),28 g_3(\tau)$ the coefficients of $z^2, z^4$ in the Laurent expansion of $\wp_\tau(z)$ at $z=0$)
- The defining [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant) of $g_2(\tau),g_3(\tau)$ are holomorphic on the upper-half-plane,  $1$-periodic and weight $4,6$ invariant under $z \mapsto -1/z$, and since they converge as $\tau \to i\infty$ (absolute convergence of the defining series) they are modular forms  $\in M_4(SL_2(\mathbb{Z})),M_6(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ and $\Delta(\tau) = g_2(\tau)^3-27g_3(\tau)^2 \in M_{12}(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$.
- $\Delta(\tau) = \prod_{j<l} (e_j(\tau)-e_l(\tau))$ is the discriminant of $4x^3-g_2(\tau) x-g_3(\tau) = 4 \prod_{j=1}^3(x-e_j(\tau))$ so $\Delta(\tau) = 0 $ implies the cubic  has a double root and $E_\tau$ is not an elliptic curve. Thus $\Delta(\tau)$ is non-zero on the upper-half plane.
- Therefore $j(\tau)= j(E_\tau)= 1728\frac{g_2(\tau)^3}{\Delta(\tau)}$ is  meromorphic on the modular curve and non-constant and holomorphic on the upper-half plane. Whence it has a pole at the unique cusp of the modular curve that is at $i \infty$.
- And hence that $g_2(i\infty)= 60 \sum_{m \ne 0} \frac{1}{m^4} \ne 0$  implies that $\Delta(i\infty)= 0$ ie. $\Delta$ is a cusp form.

Comment: I think the algebrists, when looking at things like the Galois action on the modular curves, prefer to make $\tau(E) = j^{-1}(E)$ an abstract variable defined in term of the periods of the differentials on the elliptic curve (so the points of the modular curve are equivalence classes of elliptic curves)

Comment: There was [a story](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-00734-1_10) that the constant coefficient of certain Eisenstein series would vanish iff $\zeta(s)=0$, so showing those Eisenstein series are not cuspidal would imply $\zeta(s) \ne 0$